# How to work with multiple 'views' of the same domain model?

Tags: java, oop, rest

I'm using Jackson to parse JSON for my android app. I also intend to use it in my REST server too, so I'll be sharing my models between client and server.

I've created a POJO to model a domain object "Friend". When the client gets https://www.myserver.com/api/1/friend/1234 I want to return the serialised Friend with ID 1234, perhaps with one or 2 fields missing.

However, when a client gets https://www.myserver.com/api/1/friend/ I want to return all friend objects, but with less data that might be more appropriate to search results (e.g. just first name, last name and profile image, but excluding their list of friends, date of birth, etc.).

What pattern should I follow here so that I can represent the same underlying model in different ways depending on how it'll be accessed?

Comment: Well, as far as I understood, you are talking about 2 different actions: display friend info and list friends. Are you using something like `toString()` to display data?

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance can be an option in conjunction with `@JsonIgnoreProperties`.

You can have a class `Friend` and extend it to restrict what properties are to be serialized.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "friends", "dateOfBirth" })
class RestrictedFriend extends Friend {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you want to use Inheritance.  Have a base class with fields that you want to share with everyone, and a sub-class which has more restricted data.  Have two JSON APIs, one for public info, and one for public+secure info, and serialize the base class or sub-class object based on which API was called.

Comment: inheritance seems a bit sloppy and inflexible. Is there anything like django-tastypie in the java world?